# SymPy Вычислить значение

Tags: python, sympy

Мне вычислить значение. Вот выражение.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал верхнюю левую часть и он мне выдает `'Tuple' object has no attribute 'as_coeff_Mul'`
Вот код

```
expr = ((((1+Rational(1,5))/(Rational(17,40)+0.6-0.005))*1,7)/(Rational(5,6)+(Rational(1,3)+1)-(1+Rational(23,30))))
expr
```

Если убрать одно деление то он выдает следующее.

```
expr = (((1+Rational(1,5))/(Rational(17,40)+0.6-0.005))*1,7)
expr
(1.17647058823529,7)
```

Почему он выдает вот это? Если я правильно понимаю, то это кортеж. Как правильно написать, чтобы он считал как нужно?

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке Python есть тип Fraction (from fractions), его достаточно для вычисления этого выражения, в этом случае не обязательно использовать SymPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вместо `1.7` написали `1,7`, что воспринимается как кортеж (`tuple`).

```
expr = ((((1+Rational(1,5))/(Rational(17,40)+0.6-0.005))*1.7)/(Rational(5,6)+(Rational(1,3)+1)-(1+Rational(23,30))))
```

---

```
In [48]: expr
Out[48]: 5.00000000000000
```